# Identifying exact terms that satisfy a Lucene query

Tags: lucene

Is there a way with Lucene 4.4 to determine exactly which terms satisfied a query? I need to highlight only terms that caused the document to be returned, not the same term elsewhere in the document. For example, given the document:

```
We are going to visit the White House today. I hear it is painted white.
```

and the phrase query `"white house"`, I want to highlight these terms:

```
We are going to visit the <b>White</b> <b>House</b> today. I hear it is painted white.
```

I've been using PostingsHighlighter, but it will highlight the word "white" in the second sentence as well. I don't want that because the single term "white" does not satisfy the phrase query.

It looks like the only information that comes back from a search are the document IDs and scores. I don't really care about scores for the purpose of relevancy ranking, because I'll be working with all of the documents returned. Is there something I could do with custom scoring that would preserve the information I need? Or is there a better approach that I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be intended behavior of `PostingsHighlighter` (see [this discussion](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-4825?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3acomment-tabpanel&focusedCommentId=13600572#comment-13600572)).  You might consider using [`Highlighter`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/highlighter/org/apache/lucene/search/highlight/Highlighter.html), instead.

Comment: Thanks, femtoRgon. That did what I wanted.